# Powershell Printing Custom per Printer Permissions

Tags: powershell, security, acl, network-printers

First off I would like to thank everyone for helping me work thru my issue.

Scope:
I am looking to write a script that will dynamically build the full set of permissions for each printer.  As each printer has it's own Dynamic Group and is not allowed to have the everyone group applied to the printer.

Example:

**Printer Name:** PrinterA

**AdGroup for Printer:** gprt_PrinterA

**Other groups assigned full (Print/Manage Doc/Manage Printer) permissions to the printer :** Local Admin/Local Power User/Local Print Operator/Network Admins (Domain Group)

**Other groups with Manage Documents and Print permissions to the printer:** Endpoint (Domain Group)/Service Desk (Domain Group)/gprt_PrinterA (Domain Group)\

---

First what works and I see many examples about this across the web but does not meet my requirements:

```
$DefaultPrinterInfo = Get-Printer -Name PrinterA -Full
Set-Printer -Name PrinterB -PermissionSDDL ($DefaultPrinterInfo.PermissionSDDL)
```

IMPORTANT:
***This however does not work to meet the required specifications. The reason is the *gprt_PrinterA* group can not exist on *PrinterB*.  *PrinterB* must have the *gprt_PrinterB* Group.***

---

In one example I have attempted to:

```
Set-Printer -Name PrinterB -PermissionSDDL "G:SYD:(A;;LCSWSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;OIIO;RPWPSDRCWDWO;;;BA)"
```

I have attempted to even dynamically create the default permission groups required and if this worked then it would be easy for me to just add 1 more group that is dynamically assigned:

```
(A;;LCSWSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;OIIO;RPWPSDRCWDWO;;;BA)
(A;;LCSWSDRCWDWO;;;PU)(A;OIIO;RPWPSDRCWDWO;;;PU)
(A;;LCSWSDRCWDWO;;;PO)(A;OIIO;RPWPSDRCWDWO;;;PO)
(A;;LCSWSDRCWDWO;;;S-1-5-21-51083937-621610274-1850952788-69794)(A;OIIO;RPWPSDRCWDWO;;;S-1-5-21-51083937-621610274-1850952788-69794)
(A;CIIO;RC;;;S-1-5-21-51083937-621610274-1850952788-69792)(A;OIIO;RPWPSDRCWDWO;;;S-1-5-21-51083937-621610274-1850952788-69792)(A;;SWRC;;;S-1-5-21-51083937-621610274-1850952788-69792)
(A;CIIO;RC;;;S-1-5-21-51083937-621610274-1850952788-69791)(A;OIIO;RPWPSDRCWDWO;;;S-1-5-21-51083937-621610274-1850952788-69791)(A;;SWRC;;;S-1-5-21-51083937-621610274-1850952788-69791)
```

I kept the groups clean for easy reading but essentially just make it a continuous line with "G:SYD:" in the beginning.  Then replace the PermissionSDDL in the above powershell statement. Either way though, I keep getting the error: **"[Set-Printer : Access was denied to the specific resource]"**

---

I have even attempted to do the following:

[SetSecurityDescriptor method of the Win32_Printer class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/setsecuritydescriptor-method-in-class-win32-printer?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

[Set-PrinterPermission.ps1](https://github.com/myusefulrepo/powershell-functions/blob/master/Printer/Set-PrinterPermission.ps1)

[The Security Descriptor Definition Language of Love (Part 2)](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/the-security-descriptor-definition-language-of-love-part-2/ba-p/395258)

[Adding Multiple Permissions to a Share](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Windows/en-US/a67e3ffd-5e41-4e2f-b1b9-c7c2f29a3a12/adding-permissions-to-an-existing-share)

These did put me on the correct path! It lets me replace the permission on the printer. But it strips all existing permission, putting on only the single permission specified for the printer.  I need to apply a whole set of permissions to the printer as you see above. I am a little out of my realm but learning how to build a Multi-ACL Package to apply to the printer.

---

I am ok with replacing all permissions, if I can assign a whole set of permissions, or simply add and remove to the existing permissions if they do or not exist.

What I have learned in my research the permission sets need to be:

> ## Print/Manage this Printer
>
> ```
>     # G:SYD:(A;;LCSWSDRCWDWO;;;$SID)
> ```
>
> ## Print
>
> ```
>     # G:SYD:(A;;SWRC;;;$SID)
> ```
>
> ## Print/Manage this Printer/Manage Documents/Special Permissions
>
> ```
>     # G:SYD:(A;;LCSWSDRCWDWO;;;$SID)(A;OIIO;RPWPSDRCWDWO;;;$SID)
> ```

I hope someone the help me figure out a solution please.

---

Ok so after extensively researching I am getting closer.
The "Set-PrinterPermission" script is on the correct path. What I have had to do, is stripped out the ACE function from the script to place it into it's own function.

```
function New-PrinterACE
{

##[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]

    Param (
        

        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $true,
            HelpMessage = "User/group to grant permissions"
        )]
        [String]$UserName,

        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $true,
            HelpMessage = "Permissions to apply"
        )]
        [ValidateSet('Takeownership', 'ReadPermissions', 'ChangePermissions', 'ManageDocuments', 'ManagePrinters', 'Print + ReadPermissions')]
        [String]$Permission,

        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $true,
            HelpMessage = "Permissions to apply"
        )]
        [ValidateSet('Allow', 'Deny', 'System Audit')]
        [String]$AccessType
    )

    $Ace = ([WMIClass] "Win32_Ace").CreateInstance()
    $Trustee = ([WMIClass] "Win32_Trustee").CreateInstance()

    Write-Verbose "Translating UserName (user or group) to SID"
    $SID = (New-Object security.principal.ntaccount $UserName).translate([security.principal.securityidentifier])

    Write-Verbose "Get binary form from SID and byte Array"
    [byte[]]$SIDArray = , 0 * $SID.BinaryLength
    $SID.GetBinaryForm($SIDArray, 0)

    Write-Verbose "Fill Trustee object parameters"
    $Trustee.Name = $UserName
    $Trustee.SID = $SIDArray


    Write-Verbose "Translating $Permission to the corresponding Access Mask"
    Write-Verbose "Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/setsecuritydescriptor-method-in-class-win32-printer?redirectedfrom=MSDN"
    Write-Verbose "https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Windows/en-US/a67e3ffd-5e41-4e2f-b1b9-c7c2f29a3a12/adding-permissions-to-an-existing-share"
    switch ($Permission)
    {
        'Takeownership'
        {
            $Ace.AccessMask = "524288"
        }
        'ReadPermissions'
        {
            $Ace.AccessMask = "131072"
        }
        'ChangePermissions'
        {
            $Ace.AccessMask = "262144"
        }
        'ManageDocuments'
        {
            $Ace.AccessMask = "983088"
        }
        'ManagePrinters'
        {
            $Ace.AccessMask = "983052"
        }
        'Print + ReadPermissions'
        {
            $Ace.AccessMask = "131080"
        }
    }

    Write-Verbose "Translating $AccessType to the corresponding numeric value"
    Write-Verbose "Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/setsecuritydescriptor-method-in-class-win32-printer?redirectedfrom=MSDN"
    switch ($AccessType)
    {

        "Allow"
        {
            $Ace.AceType = 0
            $Ace.AceFlags = 0
        }
        "Deny"
        {
            $Ace.AceType = 1
            $Ace.AceFlags = 1
        }
        "System Audit"
        {
            $Ace.AceType = 2
            $Ace.AceFlags = 2
        }
    }

    Write-Verbose "Write Win32_Trustee object to Win32_Ace Trustee property"
    $Ace.Trustee = $Trustee

    Return $ACE
}



  $MyPrinterAces = @()

  $MyPrinterAces += New-PrinterACE -UserName <DomainUserA> -Permission ManagePrinters -AccessType Allow

  $MyPrinterAces += New-PrinterACE -UserName <DomainUserA> -Permission ManageDocuments -AccessType Allow

  $MyPrinterAces += New-PrinterACE -UserName "DomainGroupA" -Permission ManageDocuments -AccessType Allow

  $MyPrinterAces += New-PrinterACE -UserName "DomainGroupA" -Permission 'Print + ReadPermissions' -AccessType Allow

  #https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-security-descriptor-objects#example-checking-who-has-access-to-printers
  #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60261292/explicit-access-array-from-acl-win32-api
```

This, with a few other cosmetic modifications to the "Set-PrinterPermission" script to accommodate; So that it now references this function to build the ACE's it uses and to add the ability for it to accommodate an array of multiple users/groups with permissions types.

```
function Set-PrinterPermission
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]

    Param (
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $true,
            HelpMessage = "Server or array of servers",
            ParameterSetName = 'OnePrinter'
        )]
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $true,
            HelpMessage = "Server or array of servers",
            ParameterSetName = 'AllPrinters'
        )]
        [string[]]$Servers,
        [Parameter(
            HelpMessage = "Name of the Printer",
            ParameterSetName = 'OnePrinter'
        )]
        [String]$PrinterName,
        $PrinterPermissions = 
            @( 
                @('Administrators', 'ManagePrinters','Allow'), 
                @('Power Users', 'ManagePrinters','Allow'), 
                @('Print Operators', 'ManagePrinters','Allow'), 
                @('OHD – Network Support Team', 'ManagePrinters','Allow'),
                @("OHD – PC Support Team", 'Print + ReadPermissions','Allow'),
                @("OHD - Service Desk Users", 'Print + ReadPermissions','Allow')
            )
    )



    Begin
    {
        $greenCheck = 
        @{
              Object = [Char]8730
              ForegroundColor = 'Green'
              NoNewLine = $true
         }
         ConvertFrom-SddlString -Sddl $printer.PermissionSDDL
        #Write-Host "Status check... " -NoNewline
        #Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        #Write-Host @greenCheck
        #Write-Host " (Done)"
        Write-Output "Beginning Treatment ..."

        Write-Verbose "creating instances of necessary classes ..."
        $SD = ([WMIClass] "Win32_SecurityDescriptor").CreateInstance()
        $Aces = @()

        Foreach ($PrinterPermission in $PrinterPermissions)
        {
            $Aces += New-PrinterACE -UserName $PrinterPermission[0] -Permission $PrinterPermission[1] -AccessType $PrinterPermission[2]
        }

        Write-Verbose "Write Win32_Ace and Win32_Trustee objects to SecurityDescriptor object"
        $SD.DACL = $Aces

        Write-Verbose "Set SE_DACL_PRESENT control flag"
        $SD.ControlFlags = 0x0004

    }

    process
    {
        try
        {

            If ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "OnePrinter")
            {
                ForEach ($Server in $Servers)
                {
                    $Printer = Get-Printer -ComputerName $Server -Name $PrinterName -ErrorAction Stop
                    $PrinterName = $Printer.name
                    Write-Output "Beginning treatment of: $PrinterName  On: $Server"
                    Write-Verbose "Get printer object"
                    <#
                    It seems that i can't use the Filter parameter using a var
                    $PrinterWMI = Get-WMIObject -Class WIN32_Printer -Filter "name = $PrinterName"
                    I've also noticed that I've haven't the same result using Get-CimInstance in particular with
                    $PrinterCIM.psbase.scope
                    However I'm sure that using Get-CiMInstance will be better, but i don't know how to proceed
                    then I'm using the following "Legacy" approach
                    
                    https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/the-security-descriptor-definition-language-of-love-part-1/ba-p/395202
                    https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/the-security-descriptor-definition-language-of-love-part-2/ba-p/395258
                    http://docs.directechservices.com/index.php/category-blog-menu/319-the-security-descriptor-definition-language-of-love
                    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/ace-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN
                    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-tokens

                    #>
                    #$PrinterWMI = (Get-WmiObject -Class WIN32_Printer | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Name -like "wilpa0p11" }).GetSecurityDescriptor().Descriptor.dacl
                    $PrinterWMI = Get-WmiObject -Class WIN32_Printer | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Name -like $PrinterName }

                    Write-Verbose "Enable SeSecurityPrivilege privilegies"
                    $PrinterWMI.psbase.Scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = $true

                    Write-Verbose "Invoke SetSecurityDescriptor method and write new ACE to specified"
                    $PrinterWMI.SetSecurityDescriptor($SD)

                    Write-Verbose "Treatment of $PrinterName : Completed"
                }
            } # end if OnePrinter Parameter Set

            If ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "AllPrinters")
            {
                ForEach ($Server in $Servers)
                {
                    $Printers = Get-Printer -ComputerName $Server | Where-Object { $_.Shared -eq $true } -ErrorAction Stop
                    ForEach ($Printer in $Printers)
                    {
                        $PrinterName = $Printer.name
                        Write-Output "Beginning treatment of : $PrinterName"

                        Write-Verbose "Get printer object"
                        <#
                It seems that i can't use the Filter parameter using a var
                $PrinterWMI = Get-WMIObject -Class WIN32_Printer -Filter "name = $PrinterName"
                I've also noticed that I've haven't the same result using Get-CimInstance in particular with
                $Printer.psbase.scope
                then I'm using the following approach
                However I'm sure that using Get-CiMInstance will be better
                #>
                        $PrinterWMI = Get-WmiObject -Class WIN32_Printer | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Name -like $PrinterName }

                        Write-Verbose "Enable SeSecurityPrivilege privilegies"
                        $PrinterWMI.psbase.Scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = $true

                        Write-Verbose "Invoke SetSecurityDescriptor method and write new ACE to specified"
                        $PrinterWMI.SetSecurityDescriptor($SD)

                        Write-Output "Treatment of $PrinterName : Completed"
                    }
                }
            } # end if All Printers Parameter Set
        } # End Try

        catch
        {
            Write-Error "Hoops an error occured"
            Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }

    end
    {
        Write-Output "All treatments : completed"

    }
} # end function
```

---

Now this is working great I can easily add the dynamic group as a parameter and a ACE will get assigned to the security descriptor of the printer.
Now my problem is I am unable to add the **"Manage Documents"** permission to the printer.  if anyone can help me with this I will have my project complete.
The permission is assigned  correctly for Printing only, and Manage Printer.

**Primary Issue needing help resolving:
I am so very close now...  what am I doing wrong to apply the "Manage Documents" permission to the printer ACL?**
The Image below is the results of the script trying to apply the "Manage Documents" Permissions.
[image: Image of - Manage Documents- Results from script]

Very Minor Cosmetic help:
is there a way to validate the $PrinterPermissions in the Parameters section of the code?  My thinking is to validate the parameter in the begin section of the code and exit out if one of my validations fail.  not sure if there is a better way.

Comment: Could [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48918922/9898643) be of help?

Comment: Definetly a step in the right direction.... let me play with it some